# take a matrix as input form the user .search a given number of x and print the indices at which it occurs in java

Tags: java, arrays, search, indices

The code below:

```java
package javaFullcourse;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TwoD {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter array elements:");
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        int rows=s.nextInt();
        int cols=s.nextInt();
        int numbers[][]=new int[rows][cols];
        for(int i=0;i<rows;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<rows;j++) {
                numbers[i][j]=s.nextInt();
            }
        }
        
        int x=s.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<rows;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<rows;j++) {
                if(numbers[i][j]==x) {
                    System.out.print("x is found at location("+i+","+j+")");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It automatically posts the indices without the user's input of the given number. Why?? What I am doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Are you running this code in an environment where the input might be supplied for you?  Can you explain what you are doing when you say you see "without the user input"?

Comment: Note: you use `rows` where you want `cols`: `for(int j=0;j<rows;j++) {`

Comment: j<rows, j should be less than number of columns

Answer (score 0):

The for loop on columns should use `j<cols`

Changing the for loops from

```
for(int j=0;j<rows;j++)
```

to

```
for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
```

would solve the issue.

Since the code was reading the wrong number of elements in the array, it was taking the number to be find within the array input itself.